# How can I copy only those rows which are filled in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which contains 10 rows and 7 columns.  If all columns are filled, then I am putting "ok" in column 8 otherwise Data incomplete". It is working perfectly fine, but the problem is when I leave other column blank (B, C,D & E ) except column number A & B (they are filled), it is still printing "OK" but it should be "Data Incomplete".

```
lastrow = sheet1.Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row For rownum = 1 To lastrow

    For colnum = 1 To 7

        If IsEmpty(Cells(rownum, colnum)) Then   '<== To Check for Empty Cells
            Cells(rownum, 8) = "Data Incomplete"     '<== To Enter value if empty cell found
            Cells(rownum, colnum).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            MsgBox "Please fill the column highlighted by Red"
        
        Else
            Cells(rownum, 8) = "OK"
        End If
    Next colnum
Next rownum
```

Comment: You can do all this with a formula and conditional formatting (minus the `MsgBox` of course). Is VBA a necessity? If so, `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`, or `WorksheetFunction.CountA`, may be helpful here. In any case, there is no need to loop over every individual cell.

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen says ... you can do this with formulas and conditional formatting. However if you do want a VBA solution ... rearrange your logic as follows. Note that it doesn't reset the fill color ... but you could add that if you wanted.

```
    Option Explicit
    
    
    Public Sub CheckEmptyCells()
    
        Dim lastrow As Long
        Dim rownum As Long
        Dim colnum As Long
        Dim EmptyCellFound As Boolean
        
        lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rownum = 1 To lastrow
            EmptyCellFound = False
            For colnum = 1 To 7
                If IsEmpty(Cells(rownum, colnum)) Then   '<== To Check for Empty Cells
                  Cells(rownum, colnum).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                  EmptyCellFound = True
                  MsgBox "Please fill the column highlighted by Red"
                End If
            Next colnum
                
            If EmptyCellFound Then
                Cells(rownum, 8) = "Data Incomplete"     '<== To Enter value if empty cell found
            Else
                Cells(rownum, 8) = "OK"
            End If
            
        Next rownum

End Sub
```